# Do you have to be at war with a civ to engage in theological combat?

Tags: civilization-6

In Civ 6, do you have to be at war with another civilization in order to engage w/ theological combat with their apostles/inquisitors using your own?

Comment: Similar question http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/289631/theological-combat-how-to-attack/289635#289635

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You do not need to be at war with a civilization to engage its religious units in theological combat.

In fact, the civilization you engage with won't even be mad at you for doing so, unless the theological battle results in the conversion of a city.